# Liferay Service Builder not working as expected

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I've created a Liferay plugin project which include a JSF+PF based portlet, on which I've created a `service.xml` file as I aim to create a database table.
The problem is when I try to build the service, by using the Service Builder feature, neither the service layer nor the model layer are created. Actually, and despite of the fact that 'Build Successful' message is displayed in the eclipse console, none of the Service Builder related stuff is created:

- WEB-INF/service/*,
- /src/db/*,
- META-INF/*,
- WEB-INF/sql/*,
- service.properties.

The log displayed is the following one:

```
Buildfile: C:\Liferay\carevid\liferay-6.2-ce-ga6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\carevid-entities-portlet\build.xml
build-service:
[jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: C:\Liferay\carevid\liferay-6.2-ce-ga6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\carevid-entities-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar
[delete] Deleting: C:\Liferay\carevid\liferay-6.2-ce-ga6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\carevid-entities-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar.manifest
[delete] Deleting: C:\Liferay\carevid\liferay-6.2-ce-ga6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\carevid-entities-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar
[echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Liferay/carevid/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
[echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Liferay/carevid/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
[echo] Loading file:/C:/Liferay/carevid/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
[echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Liferay/carevid/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
[echo] 20180315091704988 (El parámetro no es correcto)
[echo] java.lang.NullPointerException
[echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.getEntity(ServiceBuilder.java:1012)
[echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.getEntity(ServiceBuilder.java:1080)
[echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._parseEntity(ServiceBuilder.java:5003)
[echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:709)
[echo]  at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:230)
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Liferay\carevid\liferay-6.2-ce-ga6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\carevid-entities-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
[jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: C:\Liferay\carevid\liferay-6.2-ce-ga6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\carevid-entities-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib\carevid-entities-portlet-service.jar
[delete] Deleting directory C:\Liferay\carevid\liferay-6.2-ce-ga6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\carevid-entities-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Although Service Builder related build process finishes successfully (aparently), a `java.lang.NullPointerException` arises within that build process.

I'd really appreciate whether someone could explain to me what's happening and how I should procced to sort this problem out. Thanks.

(I'm working with liferay-6.2-ce-ga6 version)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: well - I was wondering when you'd decide to inform the volunteers here that your question is already discussed elsewhere. And the same over there. I'm assuming that you didn't read the question/answer at that link? Anyway, I'm out.

Comment: Please see if the following links help answer your question: https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/39775095, https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/51474468, https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/50536323

Comment: @stiemannkj1: thanks. Read them, but not valid for my case.

Comment: @txapeldot, seems like this could be a bug. If you think it might be one, consider reporting it here: https://issues.liferay.com/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=11374&issuetype=1. Even if it's not a bug, you should consider providing [the exact (and simplest) code and steps that can be used to reproduce your issue](http://sscce.org/). At this point, it seems like there isn't enough information here to determine what the problem is.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, but some configuration-related issue. I set up a development environment in my home PC and everything worked fine. But I don't know what can be. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could check twice your service.xml.

That NullPointer seems to be ServiceBuilder that can't find your defined entity and so it can't generate all the classes.

You can have a look to service-builder definition if you need documentation about some tags: [liferay-service-builder_6_2_0.dtd](http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_2_0.dtd)

Comment: The `service.xml`file is ok: it only has an entity, some days ago it all worked fine, and the service-build process sometimes works fine too.